# Scaled, fixed background on iOS devices

Tags: css, ipad

I am trying to make a "background" image that both scales to fill the screen, and is fixed (i.e. does not scroll with rest of content.)

I started by trying to use a true background image:

```
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DJaWd.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

But as you probably know, using this technique the image scrolls on iOS devices. So, I tried this approach using a CSS and a div:

CSS:

```
#fixedbg{
background:url('/images/contest_bkg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
position:fixed;
height:100%;
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
top:0;
}
```

The second approach does stop the image from scrolling, but the image displays 1:1, instead of scaling to fit the screen/viewport size. Any tips on how to get the image to scale while staying locked down?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've seen fixed background images cause pretty juddery-looking scrolling on desktop computers. I dread to think how it'd work out on an iOS device (which may be why `background-attachment:fixed` isn't implemented there).

Comment: did you try adding `background-size: cover;` to `#fixedbg`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-webkit-background-size: 1600px 1060px;
```

Of course px is width height of your bakcground image